# Reducir el tamaño de una imagen javascript o visual basic

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Necesito saber como puedo hacer para reducir a 1mb el tamaño de una fotografia que tomo con aplicacion movil, ya he buscado visto videos y leido, pero en todos los casos solo muestran como reducir las dimensiones, en mi caso necesito que la imagen redusca su tamaño a 1mb o menos, las imagenes pueden pesar diferente sin importar las dimensiones, hay alguna manera, ya sea en javascript o visual basic para indicarle a la aplicacion que redusca el tamaño de la imagen hasta que pese solo 1mb o hay que ir reduciendo las dimensiones y revisando el tamaño de la imagen hasta que se consiga el tamaño  deseado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un proyecto de VB.NET de formularios, añade un botón y pega este código. En mi caso, reduciendo el alto y el ancho, cada uno, a la mitad una imagen .jpg de 1,6 MB la reduce a 228 KB.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim jpg As Image
    Try
        Dim ruta As String = "C:\Users\...\...\"
        jpg = Image.FromFile(ruta + "LaImagen.JPG")
        Dim w As Int32 = jpg.Width
        Dim h As Int32 = jpg.Height
        ' Como ejemplo, reducimos el ancho y el alto a la mitad:
        Dim tp As Bitmap = Reduce(jpg, w / 2, h / 2)
        jpg = tp
        jpg.Save(ruta + "prueba.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function Reduce(ByVal img As Image, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer) As Image
    Dim imaf As New Bitmap(width, height)
    Dim pic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imaf)
    pic.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic
    pic.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height)
    Return imaf
End Function
```

Una solución no muy ortodoxa (pero práctica) es ir dividiendo sucesivamente el ancho y alto por 1, 2, 3, 4, ... y cada vez comprobar si ocupa menos de 1MB (= 1 millón de bytes = 10^6 bytes). Así, el código sería el siguiente:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim jpg As Image
    Try
        Dim ruta As String = "C:\Users\...\...\"
        jpg = Image.FromFile(ruta + "LaImagen.JPG")
        Dim w As Int32 = jpg.Width
        Dim h As Int32 = jpg.Height
        ' Empezamos dividiendo por uno:
        For div As Int32 = 1 To 10
            Dim tp As Bitmap = Reduce(jpg, w / div, h / div)
            jpg = tp
            jpg.Save(ruta + "prueba.jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(ruta + "prueba.jpg")
            Dim tamañoDeLaImagen As Int32 = fi.Length
            If tamañoDeLaImagen < 10 ^ 6 Then
                Exit For ' si la imagen ocupa menos de 1 MByte -> fin del bucle
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Para guardar la imagen en una base de datos de SQL Server, se puede guardar como variable VARBINARY(MAX). El código sería el siguiente, supuesto que la base de datos se llamase TutorialDB y la tabla que contendrá la imagen la denominamos 'Imagenes' y la imagen la guardamos con Nombre='prueba.jpg'. También incluyo el recuperar la imagen 'prueba.jpg' de la base de datos grabándola en el disco. En mi caso he hecho la prueba en un formulario con 2 botones. Un click en Button1 reduce la imagen y la guarda en la base de datos. Click en Button2 recupera la imagen y la graba en el disco con el nombre prueba2.jpg. También al formulario le he añadido un control PicturBox para mostrar la imagen ya reducida.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jpg As Image
        Try
            Dim ruta As String = "C:\"
            jpg = Image.FromFile(ruta + "imagen_A_Reducir.JPG")
            Dim w As Int32 = jpg.Width
            Dim h As Int32 = jpg.Height
            Dim tamañoDeLaImagen As Int32
            Dim nomImgReducida As String = ruta + "prueba.jpg"
            ' Empezamos dividiendo por dos:
            For div As Int32 = 2 To 5
                Dim tp As Bitmap = Reduce(jpg, w / div, h / div)
                jpg = tp
                jpg.Save(nomImgReducida, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim fi As New FileInfo(nomImgReducida)
                tamañoDeLaImagen = fi.Length
                If tamañoDeLaImagen < 10 ^ 6 Then
                    Exit For ' si la imagen ocupa menos de 1 MByte -> fin del bucle
                End If
            Next
            Dim data(tamañoDeLaImagen) As Byte
            Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
            Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(nomImgReducida)
            ' Save en formato .png (¡IMHO, mucho mejor!)
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            data = ms.ToArray()
            InsertarImagenEnSQL(nomImgReducida, data)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    ' Para crear la tabla de imágenes en el administrador de SQL Server:
    'USE [TutorialDB]
    '-- Create a New table called 'Customers' in schema 'dbo'
    '-- Drop the table if it already exists
    'If OBJECT_ID('dbo.Imagenes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    'DROP TABLE dbo.Imagenes
    'GO
    '-- Create the table in the specified schema
    'CREATE TABLE dbo.Imagenes
    '(
    '   Id        Int    Not NULL   IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    '   nombre        [VARCHAR](50) Not NULL UNIQUE,
    '   Imagen        [VARBINARY](MAX)  Not NULL
    ');
    'GO
    Sub InsertarImagenEnSQL(nombre As String, bytesImagen() As Byte)
        Try
            Dim nomImagen As String = Path.GetFileName(nombre)
            Dim sDatabase As String = "TutorialDB"
            Dim sConexion As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=" + sDatabase + ";Integrated Security=True;"
            Using conexion As New SqlConnection
                conexion.ConnectionString = sConexion
                conexion.Open()
                Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Imagenes (Nombre, Imagen) VALUES ('" + nomImagen + "', @Imagen )"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion)
                Dim sqlParam As New SqlParameter("@Imagen", bytesImagen)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
    Function ObtenerImagenDeLaBD(nomImagenBD As String, guardarComo As String) As Bitmap
        Try
            Dim sqlBin As New SqlTypes.SqlBinary
            Dim sDatabase As String = "TutorialDB"
            Dim sConexion As String = "Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=" + sDatabase + ";Integrated Security=True;"
            Using conexion As New SqlConnection
                conexion.ConnectionString = sConexion
                conexion.Open()
                Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT Imagen FROM Imagenes WHERE Nombre = '" + nomImagenBD + "'"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion)
                Dim oFileStream As System.IO.FileStream
                oFileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(guardarComo, System.IO.FileMode.Append)
                Using myReader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    While (myReader.Read())
                        Dim data As Byte() = myReader(0)
                        oFileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                    End While
                    oFileStream.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim guardarComo As String = "c:\prueba2.jpg"
        ObtenerImagenDeLaBD("prueba.jpg", guardarComo)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(guardarComo)
    End Sub
```

Comment: gracias pero como hago para saber si el tamaño es el correcto? y una cosa mas despues de comprimir la imagen debo enviarla a un procedimiento almacenado en sql server, como tendria que guardar la imagen antes de enviarla a la base de datos?

Comment: ¿Acaso la imagen debe cumplir un ancho o un alto fijo?

Comment: no, puede ser cualquier ancho y/o alto, el caso es que la imagen no debe pesar mas de 1mb